Quoting a shell command inside an osascript command run by a shell inside a JSON file
I have the following line for my Sublime text build system json:
"shell_cmd": "osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"ssh root@1.2.3.4 \"'"

It works fine, but now I should add -t 'ls -la; bash -l'
after ssh command. I wanted to escape ' characters with backslash (\'), but Sublime doesn't accept it:
"shell_cmd": "osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"ssh root@1.2.3.4 \'ls -la; bash -l\'\"'"

I tried to replace " with ' and vice versa, but it also doesn't work with Sublime.
What else can I try?
Upd. here is the command, which works well from the command line:
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "   ssh root@1.2.3.4 -t \"ls -la; bash -l\"  "  '


try "ssh root@1.2.3.4\" \"cd ..\"'"

Single quotes don't require escaping in JSON, and in shell they can't be escaped inside other single quotes at all (you need to exit the single quoted context to create a single quote literal).

@GoinOff, it doesn't work

How about showing us the command you want to run as it would be run at a shell, and we can tell you how to escape it as JSON?

@CharlesDuffy there is no way to exit the single quoted context since the whole command should be passed to osascript

That's not true. Context is evaluated character by character, so you can have different parts of a single argument quoted different ways.

A bigger issue here is that ssh root@1.2.3.4 'cd ..' doesn't do anything useful (because it connects to 1.2.3.4, runs cd .., and then disconnects and exits, so the shell that the cd was run in has exited and the cd no longer has any effect). If you want to leave an interactive shell open (for example), that requires a different formulation.

Anyhow -- figure out the correct shell command to run to achieve your desired command first, figure out correct shell quoting for that command second; figure out osascript quoting third, figure out JSON quoting last. One step at a time, checking your work between each stage; don't mix them.

@CharlesDuffy, thanks. I've corrected the question to show the full ssh command. command; bash -l should be used. I am working on bash command now.

BTW, do you have a modern version of bash available, or should I target any answer for the ancient 3.2 release Apple ships? (use echo "$BASH_VERSION", not bash --version, to check what you're running; if the result is empty, that implies that you're in zsh or another shell instead of bash at all).

GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0)

For the JSON part, your best bet is to use a programming language that can format JSON for you, given a character string. In shell you can use the jq utility (you can install it on a Mac with homebrew).

Do you know if your shell_cmd is executed with that same version of bash, or is it using /bin/sh?

The doc http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/build_systems.html#shell_cmd says it uses bash.

BTW, I'd argue that the current title really undersells the complexity of this question -- it's not just quotes within quotes, it's shell quoting inside applescript quoting inside JSON quoting. (My answer passes variables to applescript on its argv to bypass any need to do applescript quoting, but your original code is trying to hardcode correctly-quoted applescript code).

Indeed, if it wasn't easier to just build an answer, one could argue that this should be split into a separate question for each layer (and at least two such layers we do already have existing duplicates for, so it'd be only one net-new question, just one with a properly narrowed scope).

Don't try to figure out quoting by hand when it can be at all avoided: instead, let tools do the work for you. For example, let's say you have a working shell command:
ssh 1.2.3.4 'cd .. && bash -l'

If you want to create a shell string containing that command, first put it in an array, then ask the shell to quote it:
cmdArr=( ssh 1.2.3.4 'cd .. && bash -l' )
cmdStr="${cmdArr[*]@Q}"

In bash 5.x or later, this will store something like 'ssh' '1.2.3.4' 'cd .. && bash -l' in your string.
The next step would typically be to figure out how to escape the contents of cmdStr to be safely substituted into osascript source code without risk of injection vulnerabilities -- but we can sidestep this entirely by passing cmdStr out-of-band from the osascript source code, on the command line argument vector (argv). osascript source that looks on the argv for the text of a shell command to run might look like the following:
osascript -- - "$cmdStr" <<'EOF'
  on run(argv)
    return tell application "Terminal" to do script item 1 of argv
  end
EOF

...but we want a string containing a shell command that runs that osascript code (with the shell string created by our previous escaping operation passed to it), right? Well, one way to assemble one might be:
# generate a shell string containing the command we want to run
cmdArr=( ssh 1.2.3.4 'cd .. && bash -l' )
cmdStr="${cmdArr[*]@Q}"

# text of osascript code that runs its first argument in terminal
osascript=$(cat <<'EOF'
  on run(argv)
    tell application "Terminal" to do script item 1 of argv
  end
EOF
)

# one array per simple command; pass script on stdin to osascript
# ...and command on argv of osascript interpreter
write_script_arr=( printf '%s\n' "$osascript" )
run_script_arr=( osascript -- - "$cmdStr" )

# finally, assemble those pieces together
full_cmd_str="${write_script_arr[*]@Q} | ${run_script_arr[*]@Q}"

Okay! Now we just need to make that into JSON. Fortunately, that's something jq will do for you automatically:
jq -R '{"shell_cmd": .}' <<<"$full_cmd_str"

...and there we are! Output is something like:
{
  "shell_cmd": "'printf' '%s\\n' $'  on run(argv)\\n    tell application \"Terminal\" to do script item 1 of argv\\n  end' | 'osascript' '--' '-' ''\\''ssh'\\'' '\\''1.2.3.4'\\'' '\\''cd .. && bash -l'\\'''"
}

...and as long as your shell_cmd is executed by bash (not /bin/sh, which doesn't support the $'...' syntax!), it'll work perfectly.

Many thanks for you help. The result string is not human readable, but it works!
